# Floating point error with long double

Tags: c, floating-point

If wrote a program in C to get a feel for the magnitude of floating point error with respect to repeated division.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Enter a decimal number as the first positional " 
                "argument\n");
        printf("Enter the maximum number of digits to print as the " 
                "second positional argument\n");
        return 0;
    }   

    long double d;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%Lf", &d);
    int m;
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &m);

    int i;
    char format[10];
    for (i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        printf("(%d digits)\n", i); 
        sprintf(format, "%%.%dLf\n\n", i); 
        printf(format, d); 
    }   

    long double p = d;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        printf("(%Lf/10e%d with %d digits)\n", d, i, m); 
        p = p/(long double)10.0;
        printf(format, p); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is one line of the output when run with the following arguments

```
$ fpe 0.1 700
.
.
.
(0.100000/10e180 with 700 digits)
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000999999999999999999969819570700939858153376
736698732853283605408116087882762948991724868957176649769045358705872354052
261113540314114885779914335315639806061208847920179776799404948795506248532
485303630811119507604985596684233990126219304092175565232198569923253737561
276484626462077772036038845251286782974821021132356946292172207615386395848
331484216638642723800290357587296443408362280895970909637712494349003491485
594533190659822910753768473307578901199121901299804449081420898437500000000
000000000000000000000000000
.
.
.
```

Here we observe 485 digits of floating point noise. This was compiled with gcc 4.4.3, which I'm assuming is using 80bit extended precision. However, 485 decimal digits is way more than 80 bits of information. So, my question is, where is this information coming from?

Comment: As Software Monkey states, you cannot convert the floating point number exactly to a decimal, so what you see is equivalent to 1/3 being 0.33333333333...

Comment: AFAIK, for 80-bit precision you need to compile with `-mfpmath=387` (at least on x86-64) in order to use the FP co-processor. The default is `-mfpmath=sse` which I think doesn't support 80-bit precision.

Comment: You actually do need that many digits to represent the exact value of the long double.

Comment: @R.. However, 80bits can only represent 1208925819614629174706176 different values.

Comment: The issue is that those 1208925819614629174706176 values are not succinctly representable in decimal.

Comment: @R.. Ok, so would you agree that this 485 decimal digit number that we see for (long double)(0.1/(10e180)) comes from a universe of 1208925819614629174706176 possible values?

Comment: @NikosC. I get the same result when compiling with -mfpmath=387

Comment: Yes, of course. And there are plenty of decimal numbers with fewer places (e.g. only twenty-some places) that are closer to this ld80 value than to any other possible ld80 value. But they're not exact representations of it; they're approximations of it.

Comment: "However, 80bits can only represent 1208925819614629174706176 different values." -- Yes, so? If you print all of the float values, you will only see that many distinct values, not 10^485 different values ... the representation is not optimally compact.

Comment: @NikosC. “for 80-bit precision you need to compile with -mfpmath=387” No! Using `-mfpmath=387` means that **all** computations are made with 80-bit extended precision instead of the operation's type's precision. But the FP stack remains available for `long double` even when using `-mfpmath=sse` (i.e. when the compiler is generating SSE instructions for `float` and `double`).

Comment: Calling it "noise" is dangerous.  It has *none* of the statistical properties that people expect from "noise", and the effects of attempting to use the low bits of FP as a noise source are quite problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no extra information printed. The value printed is exactly the value of `p`.

After 180 iterations, `p` is +0x1.A8E90F9908E0CA56p-602, which is 15309010345804195115•2<sup>-665</sup>. The IEEE 754 standard **defines** the value of a floating-point number to be a sign (+1 or −1) multiplied by an integer power of two (determined by the exponent field of the number) multiplied by the value of its significand (the fraction portion). So every floating-point number has a specific value. The above is the value of `p`. In decimal, that value is exactly .9999999999999999999698195707009398581533767366987328532836054081160878827629489917248689571766497690453587058723540522611135403141148857799143353156398060612088479201797767994049487955062485324853036308111195076049855966842339901262193040921755652321985699232537375612764846264620777720360388452512867829748210211323569462921722076153863958483314842166386427238002903575872964434083622808959709096377124943490034914855945331906598229107537684733075789011991219012998044490814208984375•10<sup>-181</sup>.

That is the value produced by your program. So, your output formatter has printed exactly the value of `p`. It did a great job.

In fact, all around, floating-point did a great job. That value is the long double value that is closest to 10<sup>-181</sup>. It is impossible to get any closer in a long double. So, even after hundreds of arithmetic operations, the errors did not grow.

There is no new information here. If we were told the bits that were in the representation of `p`, we could have produced the same hundreds of decimal digits. They do not tell you anything new. However, they are also not garbage; they are exactly determined by the value of `p`.

Comment: The OP's confusion is in thinking that, because 485 digits are printed, they represent log2(10^485) bits of information ... but no, the representation is not compact; only 2^80 values occur.

Answer (score 0):

To add some further information to Eric's excellent answer, the 181st iteration computed the way you did, happens to be the long double nearest to 10^-181, but that does not work for every n...

For example, `1/10.0/10.0/10.0/10.0 != 1/10000.0` when computed in long double.

Using my own float emulation package in squeak Smalltalk http://code.google.com/p/arbitrary-precision-float/, I can say that out of first 300 10^-n, 77 are the nearest long double value, 223 are not.

```
(1 to: 300) count: [:n |
    ((1 to: n) inject: (1 asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64) into: [:p :i | p/10])
    ~= ((10 raisedTo: n negated) asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64)]
```

And difference peak is 4 ulp for 10^-218.

```
(1 to: 300) detectMax: [:n |
    (((1 to: n) inject: (1 asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64) into: [:p :i | p/10])
    - ((10 raisedTo: n negated) asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64)) abs
    / (2 raisedTo: -63+((10 raisedTo: n negated) floorLog: 2))].
```

Here is the evolution of error in term of ulp:

```
(1 to: 300) collect: [:n |
    ((((1 to: n) inject: (1 asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64) into: [:p :i | p/10])
    - ((10 raisedTo: n negated) asArbitraryPrecisionFloatNumBits: 64))
    / (2 raisedTo: -63+((10 raisedTo: n negated) floorLog: 2))) asInteger].

#(0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0
  0  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2
 -3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2
 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -3
 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -3 -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2 -1
 -1 -2 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1  0 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -4 -3 -2
 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -1 -2 -2 -1 -2
 -2 -1 -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0
  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0
  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0)
```